# Pattern matching in powershell to rename folder

Tags: powershell

I am trying to script to rename username folders, but some of the folders are named `USERNAME_S11-121-121...`. I want to verify path using `test-path` with wild cards and `rename-item` doesn't take wild cards.

Is there a way I can use `test-path` and `rename-item` with just username and exclude everything except username.

I don't know if `test-path $path*` is correct way of doing it?

```
 Function Reset-Profile {
           param(

                    [parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
                    [string] $UserName,
                    [parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1, ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]         
                    $Server
                )
                process{

                    $SelectedUser = $UserName
                    $randomNumber = Get-Random

                    Foreach($UserName in $Server){

                            $paths = @(
                                "\\$Server\c$\users\$SelectedUser"     #local profile               
                                "\\server01\users$\$SelectedUser", #roaming profile
                                "\\server02\usersupmprd$\$SelectedUser" #roaming profile
                                )

                            foreach ($path in $paths)
                            {
                                if(test-path $path or test-path $path*)
                                { 


                                    Rename-Item -path $path -NewName "$SelectedUser.$randomNumber"              

                                    break;
                                    write-host profile renamed under $path to 
                                    $SelectedUser.$randomNumber

                                }
                                else{ write-host path not found}                      

                            } 
                    }
                   }
}
```

Comment: There are some typos in your code. `or` needs to be `-or` and after your `write-host` statements the text needs to be a single string encapsulated by either single or double quote marks. It would be also worthwhile adding the missing closing curly brackets so that your code is complete (and therefore verifiable). It also wouldn't hurt to include an example of how your function is executed.

Comment: There is a comma in ` $paths` array (and an unnecessary on eat the end of the array).

Comment: This probably needs brackets: `if((test-path $path) -or (test-path $path*))` but to be honest this could be simplified to: `if(test-path $path*)` and it would still cover both test cases.

Comment: I'm not sure this makes much sense to me `ForEach($UserName in $Server)` are you expecting `$Server` to sometimes be an array of servers? Inside this `ForEach` you then use $Server which would be the collection not the item.

Comment: yes, I am expecting $Server to be array of server at times. the profile could be residing in multiple servers.

Comment: @MarkWragg `write-host` works fine without quotes, it takes the text as string parameters and prints them with a space between them. Ideally it would have, but it doesn't need it, it's not broken like `-or` written as `or` is broken.

Comment: Oh interesting! You learn something new every day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested, but try this:

```
Function Reset-Profile {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [string] $UserName,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1, ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]         
        [string[]] $Server
    )    
    Process{

        $randomNumber = Get-Random

        ForEach($Host in $Server)
        {
            $paths = @("\\$Host\c$\users\$UserName",        #local profile               
                       "\\server01\users$\$UserName",       #roaming profile
                       "\\server02\usersupmprd$\$UserName") #roaming profile

            ForEach ($path in $paths)
            {

                if(test-path "$path") 
                {             

                    $CurrentPath = Get-Item "$path"

                }

                elseif(test-path $path_*)
                {
                    write-host $path
                    $CurrentPath = Get-Item "$($path)_*" #it's necessary to put $path_ in parenthesis otherwise it conflicts with some internal command and gets the path of the directory I am working in.
                    write-host $CurrentPath
                }
                else {
                    Write-Warning "Path not found"
                }


                if($CurrentPath.Count() -eq 1)
                {                 
                    Rename-Item -Path $CurrentPath -NewName "$UserName.$randomNumber"              
                    Write-Verbose "Profile renamed under $path to $UserName.$randomNumber"

                } elseif ($CurrentPath.Count -gt 1) { 
                     Write-Warning  "Multiple matches for $path"
                } else { 
                     Write-Warning "Path $path not found" 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

- Added `[string[]]` in front of `$Server` so that it explicitly accepts array input (as well as a single string).
- Changed `ForEach($Username in $Server)` to `ForEach($Host in $Server)` and made use of `$Host` so that it loops through the servers correctly.
- Uses `Get-ChildItem $Path*` to get any matching paths. Then checks if a single path has been returned, if it has then it will do the rename, if it's multiple 
  or if there was no match it will warn you as such.
- Changed `write-host` to `write-verbose` which will require use of the `-verbose` switch to be seen. `Write-host` is an anti-pattern, particularly in a Function.

**How to execute:**

I suggest you run this as follows initially (because i've added `[cmdletbinding()]` at the top of your function it now supports `-WhatIf` and `-Verbose` which should pass in to the `Rename-Item` cmdlet and will show you what it does. If it looks right, simply remove `-WhatIf`:

```
Reset-Profile -Username TestUsername -Server Localhost -WhatIf -Verbose
```

Comment: it pretty much works but I wanted to concatenate everything from right side before '_' (underscore) because some of the usernames are like Username1_ , Username2_ due to same names and Get-Childitem is giving me multiple result for those.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean. Can you perhaps give an example?

Comment: let's say there are usernames like sharman_S123123 , sharman1_S1123123, sharman1a_S11231. I wanted to get the exact username before underscore rather than Get-Childitem returning 3 different users.

Comment: Oh I see now, the shortest of those would also match the other two. If it's always an underscore after the username then I think you can just change the `get-childitem` part to this: `$CurrentPath = Get-ChildItem "$path_*"`

Comment: it would have been easy if all the usernames had underscore after the username but some of them are just like sharman and others are sharman_S11212 . So, there are just two scenarios one with just the username and other with Username_blahblah

Comment: I've amended my answer to add `$CurrentPath = Get-ChildItem "$path";
                If (-not $CurrentPath) { $CurrentPath = Get-ChildItem "$path_*" }` which should cover your two scenarios I think.

Comment: @NikhilS I noticed you unaccepted the answer :(. Is something not working?

Comment: I made some changes and it worked. I also edited your post and accepted the answer but the edited version wasn't reviewed by you so it didn't show up here, I had to unaccept the answer for now. I will be back to work on friday and I will try again to edit your answer.

Comment: Ok thanks. For some reason it looks like your edit has been lost so you might need to submit it again (or just let me know what needs changing).

Comment: Hey I have made the edits. Could you review and post the changes?